# Backbone: one Model Two Views?

Tags: model-view-controller, backbone.js

I'm learning how to use Backbone and Parse to create a survey website. 
I've seen similar questions on Stack Overflow. However my question is a little different.
On this website the user can make his own survey. Suppose for now that there are two types of questions user can post: multiple choices and free response. I created a backbone Model called Question as follows.

//Question Model

```
//----------------------
var Question = Parse.Object.extend(
"Question", {
//Default attributes for the todo
defaults: {
    content: "What's your name",
    type: "free_response",
    choices: []
},
initialize: function() {
      if (!this.get("content")) {
              this.set({"content": this.defaults.content});
     }
      if (!this.get("type")) {
              this.set({"type": this.defaults.type});
     }
      if (!this.get("choices")) {
              this.set({"choices": this.defaults.choices});
     }
}

});
```

So I also want to create QuestionView that can display a question. But it should display multiple choices and free response differently. 
So what is the best way to display a Question differently according to its type? 
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you manually applying the defaults? And using an array in `defaults` can cause problems, you should use a function for `defaults` if you're going to include mutable values.

Comment: yeah, I indeed had trouble with the array, it doesn't seem to do what I expected (which was I could append item to the array). What do you mean by by using function for defaults?

Comment: You can use a function for [`defaults`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) instead of an object: `defaults: function() { return { ... } }`. That will give you a distinct set of defaults for each model.

Comment: Okay. I will try now. Do you think in that case I can still make choices as type of array? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You just have to be careful how you use it. For example, `a = m.get('a'); a.push(6); m.set('a', a)` won't trigger a `"change:a"` event because `m.attributes.a` and `a` are the same reference.

Comment: Oh I kind of see. Does that mean I need to create a new Array and do m.set('a', newArray)?

Comment: Also I'm confused by that even if I set choices as an array at first, when I do alert(question.choices). It doesn't how anything.

Comment: Yes on the "create new array" bit, `_.clone` or a separate "append new thing" method might be helpful here. You want to look at `question.attributes.choices`, the attributes that `get` and `set` work with are in `attributes`, they're not direct properties on the model.

Comment: hey, thanks. But my bug got weirder and weirder now. So I have a function lie this: addOption: function() {
            alert("enter addOption");
          var option = $("#options").val();
            alert("add  " + option + "to the question");
          var old_choices= this.currentQ.attributes.choices;
          alert("old choices is " + old_choices);
          var new_choices = old_choices.slice().push(option);
          alert("new_choices is "+ new_choices);
          this.currentQ.set({choices: new_choices});
          alert("leave addOption");
        },

Comment: then what I got from alerts are (suppose I type "hey" as input): "enter addOption", "add hey to the question", "old choices is  ", "new_choices is 1", "leave addOption". I can't understand at all where that 1 comes from...

Comment: What does [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) return?

Comment: I see what you meant. Such a silly mistake!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your questionView template add an `if` statement:

```
<script type="template/underscore" id="QuestionView">
<%- content %>
<% if (type === 'free_response') { %>
<textarea name="answer<%- id %>"></textarea>
<% } else { _(choices).each(function (choice) { %>
<input type="radio" name="answer<%- id %>" value="<%- choice %>"> <%- choice %>
<% });} %>
</script>
```

For more on how to use underscore templates see: 
http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template

Comment: Sorry but can you further explain this line:<textarea name="answer<%- id %>"></textarea>? Thanks!

Comment: I mean I'm not entirely sure what name="answer<%- id %>" does. Is it for retrieving users' answers later?

Comment: Also I have also been confused by <%- %>. How that "-" special? Sorry for asking so many questions at a time